# How can i test my already created iphone application with apple watch using simulators?

Tags: xcode

I have used simulator while testing my app. Now i would like to test my app on apple watch simulator. I have followed the following steps in order test this:

1. Created a project with 'MyfirstApp'(iOS>application>Single view application) and clicked on next
2. Entered Projectname, organization name, organization identifier, bundle identifier, language (objective C), device (universal) and saved it on my desktop
3. I have opened (xcode, file>new>target>watchkit app>next) and entered Projectname, organization name, organization identifier, bundle identifier, language (objective C), checked both the check boxes, Project(selected my project), embed in application(none) and clicked on 'Finish'
4. Clicked on activate in the pop-message.
5. Selected myapp wtackkitapp and selected the iphone5s
6. Build the application
7. My app has been displayed in the iphone simulator and i did few actions on the app but i couldn't observe anything on apple watch simulator except black blank screen.

Comment: Have you develop anything in your Apple WatchKit Extension and in your Apple WatchKit app? I mean, have you developed something specific for AppleWatch or only the iPhone version? Because if you want to run an app in a AppleWatch simulator, you must develop something more.

Comment: Nope i haven't developed anything. Please let me know what should i develop. Or please refer me the link where i can get the related info. In between  thank you so much for the responding to my question.

Comment: This would be a very big answer. You must follow some tutorial or manual to develop your own WatchKit app

Answer (score 1):

iPhone Applications do not run on the watch.  You need to create a WatchKit extension and bundle it in your iPhone application.  The WatchKit extension (running on the phone) will communicate with the watch to display the content that you want drawn on the watch.